# Buildspec file not found on Deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

Having the following error message during my deploy stage:

```
YAML_FILE_ERROR: stat /codebuild/output/src153423653/src/infrastructure/buildspec.storybook-deploy.yaml: no such file or directory
```

Which is odd, because I reference a buildspec the same way from the same path for my build stage and have no such problem. Any ideas what could cause that?

```
CodeBuildStorybookBuild:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    ...
    ...
    ...
        BuildSpec: "infrastructure/buildspec.build-storybook.yaml"
    ...
    ...
    ...

  CodeBuildStorybookDeploy:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    ...
    ...
    ...
        BuildSpec: "infrastructure/buildspec.storybook-deploy.yaml"
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

The dots, of course, as where I omitted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you output and import the artifact into that stage

In your build step

```
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: !Join ['-', [ !Ref 'AWS::StackName', SourceArtifact ] ]
```

In your deploy step

````
         InputArtifacts:
            - Name: !Join
              - '-'
              - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
                - SourceArtifact
            OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: !Join
              - '-'
              - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
                - BuildArtifact
            RunOrder: 1
    ```
````

Comment: Yeah this was the issue!